# Array of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I am trying to create an Python array of dictionaries where the input order is important and the data may be of various types. (I.e. string, integer, float, etc.)

Here's what an example would look like in Lua:

```
build =
{
    { 
        Type =                  SubSystem, 
        ThingToBuild =          "fighter",
        RequiredResearch =      "",
        RequiredShipSubSystems =    "",
        DisplayPriority =       0,
        DisplayedName =         "$7000",
        Description =           "$7001"
    },
    { 
        Type =                  SubSystem, 
        ThingToBuild =          "corvette",
        RequiredResearch =      "",
        RequiredShipSubSystems =    "",
        DisplayPriority =       0,
        DisplayedName =         "$7002",
        Description =           "$7003"
    },
    { 
        Type =                  SubSystem, 
        ThingToBuild =          "frigate",
        RequiredResearch =      "",
        RequiredShipSubSystems =    "",
        DisplayPriority =       0,
        DisplayedName =         "$7004",
        Description =           "$7005"
    },
}
```

How would I accomplish this using similar shorthand/syntactic sugar in Python? Thanks.

Comment: Will Python remember the order in which the list/dictionary items are inputted?

Comment: What have you already tried, and where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Python. [This site](https://www.codevscolor.com/ordereddict-python-example) says to use an `OrderedDict` but does not use the shorthand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python's arrays are called lists, you put them in square brackets.

Dictionaries are in curly brackets, but literal keys have to be quoted, and you use `:` to delimit the keys and values.

```
build = [
    { 
        "Type":                  SubSystem, 
        "ThingToBuild":          "fighter",
        "RequiredResearch":      "",
        "RequiredShipSubSystems":    "",
        "DisplayPriority":       0,
        "DisplayedName":         "$7000",
        "Description":           "$7001"
    },
    { 
        "Type":                  SubSystem, 
        "ThingToBuild":          "corvette",
        "RequiredResearch":      "",
        "RequiredShipSubSystems":    "",
        "DisplayPriority":       0,
        "DisplayedName":         "$7002",
        "Description":           "$7003"
    },
    { 
        "Type":                  SubSystem, 
        "ThingToBuild":          "frigate",
        "RequiredResearch":      "",
        "RequiredShipSubSystems":    "",
        "DisplayPriority":       0,
        "DisplayedName":         "$7004",
        "Description":           "$7005"
    }
]
```

Since Python 3.7, dictionaries preserve the order of the elements. Prior to that, it was necessary to use `OrderedDict`.